# Install FreePBX With Asterisk 10?

Tags: asterisk

Is there a way to install FreePBX with Asterisk 10?  When installing FreePBX it fails:

> Checking for Asterisk version..[FATAL] Asterisk 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, or 1.8
>   is required for this version of FreePBX. Detected version is: 10.0.0

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreePBX 2.10 (currently in beta) supports Asterisk 10

Comment: I just downloaded freepbx-2.10.0beta2 and I received the same error.

Comment: The fix likely wasn't published yet. You may want to try downloading the latest 2.10 from svn: http://www.freepbx.org/v2/svn/freepbx/branches/2.10/

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just edit the part in install_amp that seems to be stopping you. I found on line On line 933:

```
if (version_compare($matches[1], "11", "ge")) {
```

Change to something not 11, I changed mine to+

```
if (version_compare($matches[1], "12", "ge")) {
```

I am running 11.5.0 asterisk